# Is there a way to get all of the keys out of a cache in Angular, specifically the template cache?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to get all of the keys out of a cache in Angular, specifically the template cache?

I don't see anything about how to do this in the documentation for the [$cacheFactory](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.%24cacheFactory) or for the [$templateCache](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.%24templateCache).  (Or from Google or SO....)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not that into the angular build in $cacheFactory, because we use the $angularCacheFactory from https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache. There you can actually do such things via keys() or keySet()

Answer (score 0):

Since the cacheFactory implements a self-contained LRU cache, you don't need to peek at the keys since you can always to use .get() to **try** to get the value. You will either hit or miss the cache.

I created a [peek()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3760) function and submitted a patch.

Comment: I just tried that and I don't think it worked.  Info only gives the name and the size - no keys.  http://jsfiddle.net/NfLfT/1/

Answer (score 0):

Template keys are 'templates-app' dependancies, so you can access them as

```
var keys = angular.module('templates-app').requires; //array of keys
```