# Query AngularJS's $cacheFactory values

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I've correctly set Restangular to cache my http requests via:

```
Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: true});
});
```

I would like, however, to be able to manually certain cached elements at a given point in time, eg when they become obsolete due to the user modifying these objects. Is there a way to do this? I've tried:

```
$cacheFactory.get('$http').info()
Object {id: "$http", size: 7}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make use of the $cacheFactory API as documented here:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

For instance, to invalidate a given cache entry:

```
$cacheFactory.get('$http').remove(myGetUrlToInvalidate);
```

myGetUrlToInvalidate is a string representation of your GET request URL. You may have to test to find out whether its the 
relative or absolute URL, check out following stackoverflow discussion for more details:

- [How to refresh / invalidate $resource cache in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059569/how-to-refresh-invalidate-resource-cache-in-angularjs)

Also of interest this stackoverflow discussion pointing to an alternate cache implementation:

- [Is there a way to get all of the keys out of a cache in Angular, specifically the template cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447713/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-of-the-keys-out-of-a-cache-in-angular-specifically-th)

Restangular resources:

- https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#can-i-cache-requests
- https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setdefaulthttpfields